# Camel CXF cxfPayload StaxSource response

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hello I am using a camel(2.17.0) cxf endpoint with dataformat = Payload. I have a processor to handle the response:

```
.to("cxf://...)
.process(new responseProcessor);
```

I get a CxfPayload with a StaxSource as a body. Any convertion to String fails because of the staxSource body. I tried convertBodyTo(String.class) and getIn.getBody(String.class) in the responseProcessor. How can I convert it to a String XML?

Comment: Camel supports the conversion in its Camel CxfPayloadConverter. The problem was solved by removing camel-cache dependency as it had  a dependency "clash" with the camel converter. It uses an older version of xalan for transformer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel supports the conversion in its Camel CxfPayloadConverter. The problem was solved by removing camel-cache dependency as it had a dependency "clash" with the camel converter. It uses an older version of xalan for transformer

Answer (score 0):

A [CXF StaxSource](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/staxutils/StaxSource.html) is a [JAXP Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html?is-external=true) so the standard way of converting it to a String would be to use the transformation API (TrAX) :

```
Source source = // your CXF StaxSource;
StringWriter stringResult = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, new StreamResult(stringResult));
String message = stringResult.toString();
```

Which is a the idiomatic JAXP way of serializing XML to a String.

Comment: There is an example of this conversion here: https://github.com/FuseByExample/cxf-webinars/blob/master/customer-ws-camel-cxf-payload/src/main/java/com/fusesource/customerwscamelcxfpayload/AdditionalCxfPayloadConverters.java

Comment: as GPI said, it can be done by writing the code provided. However Camel supports the conversion in its Camel CxfPayloadConverter. The problem was solved by removing camel-cache dependency in my pom.xml as it had  a dependency "clash" with the CxfPayloadConverter. It uses an older version of xalan for transformation. Seems like a Camel bug!